# Bootstrap - Target different carousels simultaneously from one controller?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to set up a website with **several carousels** in it. The idea is that I want to have a main carousel with indicators and controls, the secondary carousels without them, and **control all carousels simultaneously from a single carousel controls**, i.e. the main carousel.

Edit: well, actually not *all of them*, but *most* of them. I am looking specifically at targetting a group of classes/ids with a single carousel controls, but leave *some others* to still work autonomously...

Sample code:

```
<!-- One Carousel to rule them all -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>

<!-- The ruled carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is, carousels with the same ids don't work, and I am not sure how to target different ids from a single href in the carousel nav. I have tried:

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel #myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
```

or

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel, #myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
```

or

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
```

with no luck...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easy targetting all carousels on the page @Schmalzy 's solution works perfect.

Nevertheless, I figured out to target a certain group of carousels and leave the rest with their own controls inspired by this question: [put two ids in one a href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357475/put-two-ids-in-one-a-href)

Since Javascript was an option, they key is calling a JS function on the controls and pass an array of target ids and the action:

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#" onclick="slideCarousels(['myCarousel', 'myCarousel2'], 'prev')">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#" onclick="slideCarousels(['myCarousel', 'myCarousel2'], 'next')">&rsaquo;</a>
```

with the following JS:

```
function slideCarousels(ids, action) {
    var len = ids.length;
    var id = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        id = ids[i];
        $('#' + id).carousel({ slide: action });
    }
}
```

Hence, the complete final code:

```
<!-- One Carousel to rule them all -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#" onclick="slideCarousels(['myCarousel', 'myCarousel2'], 'prev')">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#" onclick="slideCarousels(['myCarousel', 'myCarousel2'], 'next')">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>

<!-- The ruled carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The mighty carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel3" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- this carousel wouldn't be affected by the controls in '#myCarousel' -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function slideCarousels(ids, action) {
  var len = ids.length;
  var id = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      id = ids[i];
      $('#' + id).carousel({ slide: action });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, your reply was so helpful, works great but I need one more favour. I want to give control to carousel navigators at top .i.e. 2nd line from top <ol class="carousel-indicators">

Comment: ! Kindly do have a look at my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class `.carousel` instead of IDs.

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href=".carousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
```

[Here is an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/w8EG9/7/)

I removed the `carousel-indicators` because this could get them out all out of sync.

You would also want to disable auto-scrolling with jQuery like so....

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false 
});
```

Comment: Awesome, that's pretty clean and actually works. Only problem though (and sorry I didn't mention this clearly) is that I don't really want to change _all the carousels_, there are some that I would like to remain autonomous... Any way to target only certain specific classes or ids...? Thx!