# Bootstrap Carousel: How to control two sliders from same indicators (not left/right navigation)?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

There are total three sliders on the page and I want to control two of them from a single indicators. In the below code, indicators start from line 2.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> <!-- Indicators -->
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
   .......
```

I was able to get it done with the help of left/right navigations by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016041/bootstrap-target-different-carousels-simultaneously-from-one-controller) on stackoverflow but I do not need that.

I again repeat, that I want to control two carousel from same indicators and not navigations. Kindly do ask questions if I didn't make myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" onclick="$('#myCarousel2').carousel(1)" class=""></li>
```

and similarly

Comment: Thanks for the help but can you implement your idea on jsfiddle please?

Comment: Dude do give me a fiddle with 2 carousels and I will do it.
Else go to http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel
Open console, copy and paste carouse html, change it's id to carousel to and write above code in first carousel's indicator. It will work !! Tested !

Answer (score 1):

add your own click handlers to the indicators and manually tell the other carousel to slide