# How to close all the menus inside an Accordion in Angular 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am new to angular 4 here I have an accordion in the structure of Category,Group and Subgroup.

If I clicked on category it shows all the groups in it and if I clicked on the groups it shows all the subgroups .

Now everything is working fine .

What I want to do is If I clicked on the Category again I want to close the accordion with all the groups which are opened before.

In my case if I opened some groups and closed the accordion then If I opened again it shows the groups opened which I have opened before .

I have reproduced my code in stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-ghebrf?file=app/app.component.html

can anyone help me to fix it .

Comment: so when you click on the highest level again you need it to close and all the sub category groups also to close right?

Comment: yes exactly @RamY

Comment: is it possible to do @RamY

Comment: Broooooooooooooooooooooo @RamY

Comment: it is definitely possible, though the approach you have used to toggle elements is new to me, usually i use component variables to toggle the accordion. I'm trying to get it working using something like [this](https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/component-event-binding-output-angular-2/).

Comment: So I can't get it with my code ah ...? @RamY

Comment: Will apply the logic in my actual project and let you know the details ,But accepting the answer now coz I can see the result that what I want to do @RamY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't believe it's possible to achieve what you are looking for just by using href and ids, because href takes only one argument. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357475/put-two-ids-in-one-a-href).

I added event bindings to check when the parent accordion is being toggled to close all the child accordions too.

Added a click event here:

```
    <a class="accordion-toggle h6" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" (click)="onToggle()"  href="#collapseTwo + i">
        {{data?.CAMD_ENTITY_DESC}}
    </a>
```

and used a ngIf here:

```
<div [id]="'collapseInnerTwo' + j"  *ngIf="accordion2==true" class="accordion-body collapse" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:3px">
```

Check the full solution here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-fjowve?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: awesome, glad i could help, please upvote the answer if it was useful.